# Find a match in a column from list of strings from another column

Tags: string, list, dataframe, compare

I have two dataframes. I need to find a match and return results in another column using below criteria.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Keywords": ["SYS", "SYS2", "SYS3"]
    }

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Lookup": ["TEST SYSTEM", "SYS", "DUMMY" , "THIS IS SYS3"]
    }
```

My expected end result is

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "LookupResults": ["SYS", "THIS IS SYS3"]
    }
```

Basically i need to find those columns with full strings that match my keywords. Note i dont want TEST SYSTEM as my result. i.e no partial.

Have tried this so far.
--Convert the keywords column to list

findwords = df['Keywords'].values

--Split the Lookup strings into a list

```
df2['words'] =  [set(words) for words in 
df2['Lookup'].str.strip().str.split()]
```

--Search using below

```
df2['match'] = df2.words.apply(lambda words: all(target_word in words for target_word in findwords))
```

I am not getting desired result . However if I do something like
findwords = ['SYS'] i am getting desired result.

Clearly i am a novice and missing some basics.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: added an answer, does it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# define the pattern from Keywords in df1
# \b : word boundary

pat='\\b('+ '|'.join(df1['Keywords'].values) +')\\b'
p
```

```
'\\b(SYS|SYS2|SYS3)\\b'
```

```
# extract pattern and filter using loc
df2.loc[df2['Lookup'].str.extract(pat)[0].notna()]
```

```
    Lookup
1   SYS
3   THIS IS SYS3
```